# Extract value from a vector?

Tags: r

I wonder how I could make the list "row_names" while getting the values from vector a and b, therby not having to write it manually

```
a <- c("",2,3,1)
b <- c("",1,2,1)
c <- c("",5,6,1)



row_names <- list(
  c( "","Rye","Wheat", "Placebo"),
  c("OR, 95% CI", "2 (1-5)" , "3 (2-6)", "1"))

 row_names
[[1]]
[1] ""        "Rye"     "Wheat"   "Placebo"

[[2]]
[1] "OR, 95% CI" "2 (1-5)"    "3 (2-6)"    "1"
```

Maybe something like this? But it doesnt work.. other suggestions?

```
row_names <- list(
  c( "","Rye","Wheat", "Placebo"),
  c("OR, 95% CI", a[[2]]"("b[[2]]"-"c[[2]]")" , a[[3]]"("b[[3]]"-"c[[3]]")" , "1"))
```

Comment: @ Ronak Shah, Data is updated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could use `paste0` to combine the strings.

```
list(c( "","Rye","Wheat", "Placebo"),
   c("OR, 95% CI", paste0(a[2], " (", b[2], "-", c[2], ")") , 
                   paste0(a[3], " (", b[3], "-", c[3], ")") , "1"))


#[[1]]
#[1] ""        "Rye"     "Wheat"   "Placebo"

#[[2]]
#[1] "OR, 95% CI" "2 (1-5)"    "3 (2-6)"    "1"
```